# Uso de instrucción enum en ANSI C para crear contante, programa tirar dados

Tags: c, enum

El programa lo transcribí del libro "Como programar en C, C++ y Java" de Deitel y Deitel de donde aprendo C en su pagina 143, figura 5.10

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

enum Estatus {CONTINUA, GANA, PIERDE}; /* enum crea una constante
                                          cuyos valores tienen un
                                          numero que los identifica
                                          como ocurrer con los
                                          arreglos */

int tiraDados(void);

/* inicio del programa con la funcion main */
int main(void)
{
    int suma,
        miPunto;

    enum Estatus estatusJuego;
    
    srand(time(NULL));

    /* la funcion time toma la hora del dia y la convierte en segundos
     * para asi cada vez que se ejecute el programa parta de un numero 
     * diferente. El argumento NULL impide la la funcion time tome los 
     * valores de la fecha espresado en cadena. El valor optenido es
     * tomado por la funcion rand en las lineas 94 y 95 
     * automaticamente. */ 

    suma = tiraDados();

    switch(suma)
    {
        case 7:
        case 11:
            estatusJuego = GANA;
            break;

        case 2:
        case 3:
        case 12:
            estatusJuego = PIERDE;
            break;

        default:
            estatusJuego = CONTINUA;
            miPunto = suma;
            printf("Su punto es %d\n", miPunto);
            break;

    } /* fin de switch */

    while(estatusJuego == CONTINUA)
    {
        suma = tiraDados();

        if(suma == miPunto)
        {   
            estatusJuego = GANA;

        } /* fin de if */
        else
        {
            if(suma == 7)
            {
                estatusJuego = PIERDE;

            } /* fin de if */

        } /* fin de else */

    } /* fin de else */

    if(estatusJuego == GANA)
    {
        printf("El jugador gana \n");

    } /* fin de if */
    else
    {
        printf("El jugador pierde \n");

    }
        
    return 0; /* finalizacion del programa con exito */

}   /* fin de la funcion main */

int tiraDados(void)
{
    int dado1,
        dado2,
        sumaTemp;

    dado1 = 1 + rand() % 6;
    dado2 = 1 + rand() % 6;
    sumaTemp = dado1 + dado2;

    printf("El jugador tiro %d + %d = %d\n", dado1, dado2, sumaTemp);

    return sumaTemp;

} /* fin de funcion tiraDados */
```

En la linea 5 del programa entiendo que enum crea una constante con tres valores pero no entiendo como funciona la linea "enum Estatus estatusJuego", no se si esta trasladando los valores a estatusJuego o como va; tampoco me queda muy claro las lineas 36, 42 y 46 que repercuten en las lineas 53, 59, 66 y 74. Gracias.

No se trata de una tarea ni nada por el estilo, estoy tratando de aprender C transcribiendo los ejemplos del libro ademas de intentar resolver los problemas.

Answer (score 2):

```
enum Estatus {CONTINUA, GANA, PIERDE};
```

Esta línea crea un tipo nuevo, `enum Estatus`. Junto con este nuevo tipo, se declaran tres posibles valores (constantes) para dicho tipo: `CONTINUE`, `GANA`, `PIERDE`. Los valores asignados a dichas constantes corren a cuenta del compilador, siendo `CONTINUE == 0`, `GANA == 1` y `PIERDE == 2`.

```
enum Estatus estatusJuego;
```

Aquí estás declarando una variable `estatusJuego` que será de tipo `enum Estatus`.

Así, dado que `estatusJuego` es una variable, puedes usarla para almacenar valores, justo como hace el programa en las líneas 36, 42 y 46:

```
estatusJuego = GANA;
estatusJuego = PIERDE;
estatusJuego = CONTINUA;
```

**Nota final**: Todo lo comentado sobre los enumerados es muy bonito, pero lo cierto es que C nunca se ha caracterizado por poseer un tipado fuerte. Realmente los tipos basados en `enum` son convertidos y tratados como enteros por el compilador. Así, la siguiente línea compilará perfectamente:

```
estatusJuego = 10;
```

Realmente no hay ninguna constante que posea el valor 10, pero es que el compilador tampoco va a verificar en ningún momento que a un enumerado le asignes valores que pertenezcan a dicho tipo... esa será tu responsabilidad como programador.

Así pues, con los enumerados se pueden hacer auténticas escabechinas, sin embargo mi consejo es que no hagas cosas raras y dejes el código lo más claro posible ya que tu salud y tu tiempo dependerán de ello... y si no me crees espera a que tus programas crezcan de tamaño.

Comment: "y si no me crees espera a que tus programas crezcan de tamaño ..." O espera que pasen 6 meses, a ver si todavia lo entiendes ...

Comment: Ok, es que no había entendido esa linea. Gracias.